# Linear regression lines in a time series data(BTCUSD) with Angles close 90 degrees and slopes with big numbers

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, trading, algorithmic-trading

I trade Bitcoin and USD. For getting regression lines values, angles and slopes, I use the `talib` library.

I'd like to compare angle of regression lines of different lengths, for example regression lines with length of 10 and 50, however when printing the angles and slopes values, almost all of angles are close to 90 degrees (positive or negative) and slopes are big numbers(positive or negative).

The code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import talib

df = pd.read_csv(r'E:\filepath\Kucoin_BTCUSDT_d.csv')
# getting a short section of df for ease in printing the results 
df = df[100:105]

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") 
df = df.set_index("date")

lrSlope = talib.LINEARREG_SLOPE(df['close'], timeperiod=5)
lrAngle = talib.LINEARREG_ANGLE(df['close'], timeperiod=5)

print(df['close'])
print('Slope', lrSlope.iloc[-1])
print('Angle', lrAngle.iloc[-1])
```

Here is the result:

```
date

2018-02-03    9199.999443

2018-02-04    8117.000002

2018-02-05    6950.001000

2018-02-06    7676.000008

2018-02-07    7572.421893

Name: close, dtype: float64

Slope -369.61550939999984

Angle -89.84498583458068
```

I think it;s because of big difference in `x` and `y` axes, `x` is `(0, 1, 2, ...`) if `date` is not set as index or `date` if it is set as index, but `y` axis is Bitcoin prices which are big numbers.

What is the problem here? is my assumption correct? what can I do to get more realistic angles (like 30, 45, 60, etc.) so that I can compare them, and set certain thresholds?

Comment: Are you regressing prices or returns? It's not clear from your code, and not immediately clear to me from the `talib` documentation that it would calculate a return for you.  Typically, regressions are performed on time-series of returns not prices.